# Word 2010 - Coversheets

Tags: windows-7, vba, microsoft-word-2010

We have created standard coversheets for several projects. These coversheets are exchanged on standard documents to make it client specific.

The font type of these coversheets is Arial.
It seems that standard format roled out at Word instal is Courier New with Paragraph setting 10 pt after and 1.5 line size.

This is causing problems. Is there a method where the coversheet format can be maintained while the remainder of the documents (or new documents) can be based on the standards as set by Office ?